the kubeapi services crash every time when I tried to deploy the PCG with creation of 72 replicas
the kubeapi services crash every time when I tried to deploy the PCG with creation of 72 replicas. kubectl command not able to run from cluster, inter cluster IP as well stopped pinging. Please help why it is happening and how to resolve this issue. KubeAPI services restarted automatically in short interval.
post restarting all the worker node in cluster. Cluster restored back to normal.

Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

What is PCG?  Do you have a [mcve], including any relevant application code?  Or are you just overwhelming the cluster, and beyond decreasing the replica count, you as an application developer can't do anything beyond ask your operations team or cloud provider for help?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
